# .NET Core custom ILogger middleware to catch long running requests

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I am slowly learning .NET Core and am struggling to get my head around the logging middleware. I have written a custom ILogger which logs out to a text file. By default, .NET core will log Information about the length of time each request takes, for example:

```
Information: Request finished in 154.0077ms 200 application/json
```

I have a requirement to log any requests that take longer than *n* ms as a warning rather than information so that in production the default log level can be set to Warning and these slow requests are still captured

At the moment I'm doing the following, which works, but only if the default log level is set to Information (which I don't want in production). Obviously changing the default to warning means that the "request finished" data doesn't even get passed to the logger.

```
Regex requestFinished = new Regex(@"(.*\s)([0-9]{1,}[.]?[0-9]{1,})([m]?s)");
Match match = requestFinished.Match(message);

if (match.Success)
{
    double timeTaken = 0;
    Double.TryParse(match.Groups[2].ToString(), out timeTaken);

    if (timeTaken > MyService.ExecutionThreshold)
    {
         logLevel = LogLevel.Warning;
    }
}
```

I suspect there's a much easier way of doing this than the above but I cannot figure it out and can't seem to find any suggestions online. Any help gratefully received.

Comment: Why not use a profiler like [MiniProfiler](https://miniprofiler.com/dotnet/AspDotNetCore)?

Comment: Have you looked into using Application Insights?

Comment: Thanks I'll explore those options